# Use linq to query blocks of text?

Tags: linq, text

I have a text file that contains some data in a "block" format:

```
source : source location
filename : somefile.txt
vendor : somevendor
version : xx.xx.xxx

source : source location2
filename : somefile2.txt
vendor : somevendor2
version : yy.yy.yyy
```

can I use Linq to query this data and if so how would you go about it?  I have used linq to query lines of data from text file many times, but never a "block" of data as above. Thanks for the input.

Comment: The answer to this question depends on how you want to identify - and parse - such a block.

Comment: each block needs to be a record that I can use to do some comparisons with, against a second and third set of data in the same format.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use LINQ, this approach is not optimized much if you have large file. Below is how to get data:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("C:\\text.txt")
                .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                .ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i += 4)
{
    var location = lines[i].Split(':')[1];
    var fileName = lines[i + 1].Split(':')[1];
    var vendor = lines[i + 2].Split(':')[1];
    var version = lines[i + 3].Split(':')[1];
}
```

Version to use LINQ:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, lines.Count()/4).Select(i => new {
        location = lines[4*i].Split(':')[1];
        fileName = lines[4*i + 1].Split(':')[1];
        vendor = lines[4*i + 2].Split(':')[1];
        version = lines[4*i + 3].Split(':')[1];
    });
```

Comment: how to retrieve all sources, filenames,vendors,versions as different list using linq query ?

Comment: this line results in a index outside of bounds error?  var result = Enumerable.Range(0, lines.Count()/4).Select(i => new {  NEVERMIND, I found the problem

Comment: @MPowers: make sure that you need to check lines.Count()%4 == 0

Comment: @Coung Le: thanks, at the very bottom of the file is an extraneous line "Operation State : Success", messing up the index